# how to display an image from a mysql blob field in symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, blob

How do I display an image from a mysql blob field in symfony? Now it's only echo the text 'Array'.

Is it possible just to add a new property to the indexSuccess.php like

```
<img src="<?php echo $persons->getPhoto('[property]') ?>" />
```

or

```
<img src="<?php echo $persons->getPhoto()->[property] ?>" />
```

to print it correctly?

Comment: Is Photo a field or a related object?

Comment: It is a field echoed in the same way as any other field in indexSuccess.php

Comment: try `$photo = $persons->getPhoto(); echo $photo['property'];`

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute contains a *location*, not the image data itself - with the exception of data URIs.

You need to create another page that sets the correct headers and outputs the image data from the DB, and point to that in your src.

The alternative is to echo a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) in the `src` attribute.

Also keep in mind that if you have output escaping on, symfony also escapes the data in your blob field while being passed to the view layer.